# SQL query - get top sold items from table with cols (saled qty, item no, no )

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

**Hello i have a table with columns:**

```
saled qty, item no, no
-3, 1996-s, 149
-2, 1996-s, 150
-2, 1968-b, 151
```

Now i should get the **top sold** products. Maybe i have to **group** somehow by item no and then sort by saled qty and then i could **select top 3** for example?

**Update:**
There are also other columns that i don't need but becuase of them i get error:

*timestamp' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

**Almost there**

```
SELECT TOP(3) [Item No_], SUM([Invoiced Quantity]) as [qty] 
FROM 
    [Demo Database NAV (7 - 1)].[dbo].[CRONUS (Schweiz) AG$Value Entry]
GROUP BY 
    [Item No_]
HAVING [Item Ledger Entry Type] = 1
ORDER BY 
    SUM([Invoiced Quantity]) DESC
```

gives error: Item Ledger Entry Type' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP(3) 
    item_no, 
    SUM(saled qty) 
FROM 
    TABLENAME 
GROUP BY 
    item_no, [Item Ledger Entry Type]
HAVING [Item Ledger Entry Type] = 1
ORDER BY 
    SUM(saled qty) DESC
```

or

```
SELECT TOP(3) 
    item_no, 
    SUM(saled qty) 
FROM 
    TABLENAME 
WHERE [Item Ledger Entry Type] = 1
GROUP BY 
    item_no
ORDER BY 
    SUM(saled qty) DESC
```

Depending on if you want pre or post aggregation filtering

Just replace 3 with whatever number of products you want.

Explanation:
When you do a group by you can only include columns in your result which are either part of the group by clause OR are being aggregated in some way. Here I've used SUM which aggregates the saled_qty column and I've ommited all the other columns from your query.

The best way to think of this is to imagine you yourself rather than SQL were grouping the data.... Say we group by item_no... how are you meant to know what to do with all the saled_qty values? You will have multiple values of saled_qty for each row of your results (One row per whatever is in your grouping clause... in this case item_no). SQL will not allow you to be ambiguous about this and so throws an error.

Comment: doesnt work because as you can see the first and second column values, i have the same itemNo so, they should be countet togheter.. thats why i thought maybe group by could do this somehow..

Comment: @user2834172 I've update my answer to solve your updated problem.

Comment: Thanks very much but one last question.. if i now only want to know this from cols having type = 1 how could i do this?

Comment: Oh thanks for that explanation, this really helps me.. i tried this with having there i have the same error. but if i only want to select those where type = 1 it should be clear for what to do

Comment: @user2834172 I've updated my answer and will expand here to teach you some more SQL.

Items in the HAVING clause have to be in the GROUP clause... just like the items being selected.

If you don't want them there then instead use a WHERE clause. I will add both to my answer for you. If you find this answers your question please mark my answer as correct for you, otherwise I'll check back soon.

Comment: this returns by every item the qty 0, yes i think the i would more like it with the where clause.. thank you for teach me sql =)

Comment: @user2834172 If the WHERE clause is what you needed then what you wanted was a pre-aggrigation filter. The WHERE stuff will happen before your GROUP by, but the HAVING happens after the data is already grouped. (Post aggrigation filter).

I find it easiest to think of it like this: WHERE filters the data used for the query, HAVING filters the results from the query... Although I'm sure some SQL gurus will not agree with my precise wording or definition!

Comment: So ive got it know! and it works like needed. And i learned a lot of stuff of grouping having and so on. So many many thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM table GroupBy itemno ORDER BY saledqty DESC
```

**Update:**

If you need to select other columns too, then include them in your GroupBy Clause also.

For Example:

```
  SELECT TOP 3 count(itemno),itemno,timestamp FROM table GroupBy itemno,timestamp ORDER BY saledqty DESC
```

Comment: i think this should work, but there are also other cols that i dont need but they produce an error.. question updated..

Answer (score 0):

It would work:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM tbl GroupBy item_no ORDER BY saled_qty DESC
```

Comment: i think this should work, but there are also other cols that i dont need but they produce an error.. question updated..

Comment: _timestamp' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause._ But i dont need those other cols just the itemno and saled_qty

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT saledqty,itemno, no
FROM Table1
WHERE saledqty IN (
SELECT TOP 3 MAX(saledqty) As Sale
FROM Table1
```